# How to open and close a file from a while

Tags: c++

I need this program to show the count of words from a file (text document). However, not reseting counter of words. its supposed to be 7 but it is displaying 62 words. I was told to close the file  from the second last  while and create a new while (which is the last one) and open the file again. I've working on this for a while. However,  after making  the changes it doesn't display the file anymore. the only thing display in the screen it s a th and account of 2 words.
    Thanks for your help

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>//step#1
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

   string word,fileName;
   char character;
   int charcounter = 0, wordcounter = 0;
   ifstream inData;// incoming file stream variable

   cout << " Enter filename or type quit to exit: ";
   cin >> fileName;

   //loop to allow for multiple files data reads
   while (fileName != "quit")
   {    
      inData.open(fileName.c_str());//open file and bind file to ifstream variable

      //loop for file not found validation
      while (!inData)//filestream is in fail state due to no file
      {
         inData.clear();//clear the fail state 
         cout <<"File not found. Enter the correct filename: ";
         cin >> fileName;
         inData.open(fileName.c_str());
      }

      inData >> character;//extract a single character from the file
      cout << "\n*****************************\n";
      while (inData)
      {
         cout << character;
         inData.get(character); 
         charcounter++;
      }

      cout << "\n******************************\n";
      cout << fileName << " has " << charcounter << " words." << endl;
      inData.close();//close the ifstream conection to the data file

      while (inData)
      {
         cout << word;

         wordcounter++;
         inData.open(fileName.c_str());
      }
      charcounter = 0; //reset character count
      wordcounter = 0;
      //port for next file or exit
      cout << "Enter a filename or type quit to exit: ";
      cin >> fileName;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post your input files, the expected output of the program, and the actual output.

Comment: This &%file              should!!,...

have exactly 7 words.

Comment: Enter filename or type quit to exit: file1.txt

*****************************
Th
******************************
file1.txt has 2 words.
Enter a filename or type quit to exit:

Comment: Enter a filename or type quit to exit: file1.txt
file1.txt data
***********************
This &%file should!!,...



have exactly 7 words.

***********************
file1.txt has 7 words.

Comment: Add them to your post, please.

Comment: comment #1 is file1.txt, comment#2 is my output , comment# is the sample i need to match. I'm new here, I don't know how to add files properly, but the sample shows  a blank space between cout<<enter file:  and file1.txt has 2 words.  thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here.It's specially important to post a [mcve]. You can [edit] your post to update it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>//step#1
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   string word,fileName;
   char character;
   int charcounter = 0, wordcounter = 0;
   ifstream inData;// incoming file stream variable

   cout << " Enter filename or type quit to exit: ";
   cin >> fileName;

   //loop to allow for multiple files data reads
   while (fileName != "quit")
   {
      inData.open(fileName.c_str());//open file and bind file to ifstream variable

      //loop for file not found validation
      while (!inData)//filestream is in fail state due to no file
      {
         inData.clear();//clear the fail state
         cout <<"File not found. Enter the correct filename: ";
         cin >> fileName;
         inData.open(fileName.c_str());
      }


      cout << "\n*****************************\n";
      while (inData)
      {
         inData >> character;//extract a single character from the file
         cout << character;
         charcounter++;
      }

      cout << "\n******************************\n";
      cout << fileName << " has " << charcounter << " chars." << endl;
      inData.close();//close the ifstream conection to the data file

      inData.open(fileName.c_str());
      while (inData)
      {
         inData >> word;
         cout << word;
         wordcounter++;
      }
      cout << "\n******************************\n";
      cout << fileName << " has " << wordcounter << " words." << endl;
      inData.close();//close the ifstream conection to the data file


      charcounter = 0; //reset character count
      wordcounter = 0;
      //port for next file or exit
      cout << "Enter a filename or type quit to exit: ";
      cin >> fileName;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to use `++charcounter` if you do not need  the result of the postfix operator. (see Herb Sutter, Andrei Alexandrescu, C++ Coding Standards Rule# 28)